# Unsure if container hierarchy is causing me positioning issues

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, position

Im building my first website and this is first time asking for help. I am unsure of how to position the sidebar widget area of my site in the position I want. Im working on making my the site fully responsive. What I am trying to accomplish is get the sidebar to "hug" the content area so they are always next to each other with a small 20-35px margin in-between them, and as screens get larger I want them to stick together. I came across this website http://uberhavoc.com, I am trying to model my sidebar and content in a similar way. Here is my site: http://peakworthy.com.

my site has the main site content area with two divs, the main content and the sidebar. I tried get the to position how i want using percentage margins, played with clears, clearfixs and everything else. I was wondering if I am approaching this wrong or if the DOM is causing issues with style hierarchy. If you have any ideas I would be greatful. been pulling hair out on this for a couple days now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd try to stay away from float if possible. Try this out instead. The display-block places them side by side and will help with the responsive feature because the sidebar will automatically jump down when space runs out, and text-align:center makes them stay in the middle of the page at larger sizes.

```
.site-content {
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    text-align: center;
}
.content-area {
    display: inline-block;
}
.site-content .widget-area {
    width: 380px;
    padding: .3em 0 .3em 4em;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting the results i wanted by eliminating the float after once i got to desktop size. thanks for the help!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using floats. Your `.content-area` has a variable width which might become an issue from page to page.

Comment: I didn't say floats were bad, they're great for positioning certain elements on a page. I just personally don't think structuring the main layout of a web page with them is best practice. Displaying it as inline-block may not work any better, but at least it's more compatible for IE.

Comment: _"I just personally don't think structuring the main layout of a web page with them is best practice."_ Using floats is not best practice? You better let these guys in on that; [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) or any other CSS framework that provides a base for developing Responsive layouts. Floats are definitely standard practice. As a side note, I do think [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) will take over floats in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your main content area and your sidebar content inside a container element. Then use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to determine a breakpoint for when the sidebar should re-flow.

Below is the basic markup of my suggested approach. The main content and sidebar content are the two siblings of a container element. They are floated left and have a percentage width applied to each. A media query is used to determine when the two columns of content should be side-by-side or stacked.

```html
<main class="cf">
    <div class="content">Main Content</div>
    <aside class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</main>
```

```css
main {
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.content,
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.sidebar {
    background-color: #bbb;
}
@media ( min-width: 480px ) {
    .content {
        width: 70%;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
        background-color: #bbb;
    }
}
```

The [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) and background colors used above are only in place for my demo and can be omitted.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vj9zq0oq/

Re-size the jsFiddle to see the content columns re-order.

Comment: I was able to make it all work! Thanks for your help